# How do I search a list of objects most efficiently?

Tags: c#, performance, list, for-loop

I have a `List<T>` of *`objects`* with a few fields.
How can I most efficiently search this list to find a certain *`object`*?
For now I just make a for `loop` which looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < theList.Count; i++)
{
  if (theList[i].certainField == whatImLookingFor)
  {
    doSomething();
    break;//to exit for loop to prevent unnecessary processing
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way I can go about this? It's usually the same field which I am comparing it too. I thought maybe to use a dictionary but am not quite sure if I should.

Comment: This will stop at the first object you find, is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I am always looking just for one specific object in the List.

Comment: Well then, I don't see how this could be improved by building a dictionary except if your object list is _really_ huge. I'd have gone for a `Map` if you were actually looking for several objects, but since you stop at the first one, you'd be taking more time building the dictionary than searching the way you currently do.

Comment: Since I am usually comparing the same field, I thought to make something like:
    Dictionary <certainFieldType, myClass> theDictionary;
so then I wouldn't need a for loop, I just do
    theDictionary[whatImLookingFor]


(whatImLookingFor should always be there)

Comment: That is true, yes, but you still need to inject into this dictionary (what language is that by the way?), so it's up to you to see if it is worth it.

Comment: c#. Well the objects would be added to the dictionary once basically, but once in the the dictionary they would be accessed many times. Thoughts?

Comment: In this case, yes, creating a dictionary can help. Your choice ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Just in general, my List has a Count of max 32, do you think it would be significantly more efficient instead of the for loop?

Comment: In case of a list with 32 entries it is probably not that critical except if you do look for the item many times a second... Write a simple console app to time it and find out!

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on your usage.

If you need to execute this many times and want to make execution as fast as possible, create a dictionary:

```
//save a dictionary somewhere
var dictionary = theList.ToDictionary(i => i.certainField);

//execution:
var item = dictionary[whatImLookingFor];
dosomething();
```

This comes at expense of creating the dictionary (longer initialization time) but gives a faster lookup O(1).

If you only need to do this once then keep your code as is (O(n) lookup).

Answer (score 0):

```
theList.First(x => x.certainField.Equals(whatImLookingFor)); //already optimized
```

BTW You don't really know how .NET Dictionary[index] operator internally implemented (eg. loop through array or using pointer linked-list in low-level)

I would recommend reading [Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379570%28v=vs.80%29) an in-depth analysis of .NET data structure efficiency (Array, Stack, Dictionary, List) though it writen years ago its still valid and worth looking at